# Any way to order Google search results by recency with descending date order?

Tags: google-search, sorting

As an example, I'll use "laughing cats" as the search term for "site:youtube.com". I'd like to sort or "order" the results by descending date (oldest to newest).

Here's an example of what I'd like to accomplish as per Kagi's method with it listing the oldest search results to the most recent:
[image: search results]

Answer (score 1):

> Sort-by-date has been retired, except within news search, where we have confidence the dates are actually valid.

Source: https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/3578318?hl=en&msgid=3882251